# For how long will the Soyuz 2.1v launcher use the old NK33 engines?

Tags: engines, launch-vehicle, nk-33, rd-19x

I understand that the Soyuz 2.1v launcher will switch from using the NK33 engine to the new RD-193 when stocks of the former are finished.

Does anyone know how many launches, beyond the two so far, are planned using the NK33 type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to now almost three years old news article ([in Russian](http://novosti-kosmonavtiki.ru/news/7229/), [Google Translate version](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fnovosti-kosmonavtiki.ru%2Fnews%2F7229%2F)) from April 2013 that quotes Energomash CEO Vladimir L. Solntsev, there were at the time in total of *about 20* [NK-33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NK-33) engines left in the warehouse, which would be enough for *about 10 launches*.

It is a bit difficult to predict how long the NK-33 supplies will last. Launch vehicle is now awaiting return to flight after the partial failure with Kosmos 2511 (Kanopus-ST) [failing to separate from the upper stage](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/kanopus-st.html) in December 2015, and it is also unclear when we'll see the first [Soyuz-2-1v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz-2-1v) launch from [Vostochny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostochny_Cosmodrome). First Soyuz-2.1a is [currently scheduled](http://spaceflightnow.com/launch-schedule/) to launch from there on April 25, but I haven't seen any announcement of Soyuz-2-1v launch from Vostochny yet. So far, only three Soyuz-2-1v launches from [Plesetsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesetsk_Cosmodrome) are expected till 2018 according to [Spaceflight 101](http://spaceflight101.com/calendar/), and usually well informed Gunter Dirk Krebs currently only lists [one planned launch](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau_det/soyuz-2-1v_volga.htm).

[According to Anatoly Zak](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/vostochny_soyuz.html), the new Soyuz-2-1v (previously referred to as Soyuz-1) configuration with RD-193 engines will be called Soyuz-2-1d, but searching the web by that moniker didn't yield any more information, I'm afraid.

---

If I had to guess, then my bet is that Baikonur will never see a Soyuz-2-1v launch at all (because of the nature of its typical payloads and target orbital inclinations, and because Baikonur isn't in Russia), and we'll see inaugural RD-193 on Soyuz-2-1v (Soyuz-2-1d?) launch from Vostochny, likely before Plesetsk runs out of NK-33 engines, somewhere around 2020. Sooner, if they decide they'll only supply Vostochny with RD-193's and keep all NK-33's at Plesetsk.

Comment: Thanks, that covers it, i.e. the quote about twenty engines left, whether they choose to use them or otherwise. Presumably Aerojet have a few unusued ones too. I do find it curious that Orbital stepped away from using them so abruptly, it was as if, albeit unstated, they were concerned about a systematic weakness.